# Ошибка вызова и использования определенной функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Определил функцию:

```
def error_func(w_0=60,w_1=0.05):
    err=0
    for i in data['Height'][:]:
        obj_err=data['Height'][i]-(w_0+w_1*data['Height'][i])
        err=err+obj_err**2
    return err
```

При вызове или использовании функции в качестве аргумента выдается ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-125-9b7dec2e508c> in <module>()
      9 x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
     10 
---> 11 plt.plot(x, error_func(w_0=60,w_1=0.05),"r", lw=3)

<ipython-input-125-9b7dec2e508c> in error_func(w_0, w_1)
      2     error=0
      3     for i in data['Height'][:]:
----> 4         obj_err=data['Height'][i]-(w_0+w_1*data['Height'][i])
      5         error=error+obj_err**2
      6     return error

C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    621         key = com._apply_if_callable(key, self)
    622         try:
--> 623             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    624 
    625             if not is_scalar(result):

C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_value(self, series, key)    2555         k =
_values_from_object(key)    2556 
-> 2557         k = self._convert_scalar_indexer(k, kind='getitem')    2558         try:    2559             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,

C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\numeric.py in
_convert_scalar_indexer(self, key, kind)
    166             key = self._maybe_cast_indexer(key)
    167         return (super(Int64Index, self)
--> 168                 ._convert_scalar_indexer(key, kind=kind))
    169 
    170     def _wrap_joined_index(self, joined, other):

C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
_convert_scalar_indexer(self, key, kind)    1374             if kind in ['getitem', 'ix'] and is_float(key):    1375                 if not self.is_floating():
-> 1376                     return self._invalid_indexer('label', key)    1377     1378             elif kind in ['loc'] and is_float(key):

C:\Conda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in
_invalid_indexer(self, form, key)    1574                         "indexers [{key}] of {kind}".format(    1575                           form=form, klass=type(self), key=key,
-> 1576                             kind=type(key)))    1577     1578     def get_duplicates(self):

TypeError: cannot do label indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.numeric.Int64Index'> with these indexers [65.78331] of <class 'float'>
```

Что не так? Функция оформлена по документации.

Comment: А зачем перебирать `for i in data['Height'][:]` и внутр обращаться к `data['Height'][i]`? Уверен, что `i` -- вещественные числа, а когда вы по ним пытаетесь получить значение по индексу происходит та ошибка

Comment: тут я хочу пройтись по всей длине датафрейма и соответственно вызывать значение столбца '['Height']' для дальнейших преобразований

Comment: Как я понимаю, та же ошибка в вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055221 и ответ на него говорит в пользу решения оt gil9red. Видимо, у Вас возникает значение индекса, равное 65.78331

Comment: Ради интереса, если написать data['Height'][int(i)] - не будет ли эта ошибка отсутствовать?

Comment: Похоже на то, что действительно всплывают вещественные числа.
Как тогда пройтись по длине датафрейма?

Comment: UPD:

Функция почему-то даже при переборе 'for i in range(25001):' выдает ту же ошибку

Comment: А можете ещё что такое `data` показать?

Comment: data, это экселевский файл с записями вида

Index,Height,Weight
1,65.78331,112.9925
2,71.51521,136.4873
3,69.39874,153.0269
4,68.2166,142.3354
5,67.78781,144.2971
6,68.69784,123.3024
7,69.80204,141.4947
8,70.01472,136.4623
9,67.90265,112.3723
10,66.78236,120.6672

в количестве 25000 строк.

Comment: Странно, у меня, если `data = {
    'Index': [1, 2],
    'Height': [65.78331, 112.9925],
    'Weight': [112.9925, 136.4873]
}` и написать условие для индекса как `for i in range(len(data['Height'][:])):`, то ошибки в этом месте нет

Comment: Могу ошибаться в формате `data`, конечно, потому что мало работал с numpy и pandas

Comment: Ошибка, а точнее некорректная работа заключалась в рискованном использовании такой формулировки 

for i in data['Height'][:]:
        obj_err=data['Height'][i]-(w_0+w_1*data['Height'][i])

для работы с DataFrame'ами есть более удобные и отлаженные методы вызывающие и отдельно строки и отдельно столбцы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы исправить синтаксическую ошибку достаточно изменить функцию следующим образом:

```
def error_func(w_0=60,w_1=0.05):
    err=0
    for i in data['Height']:
        obj_err = i - (w_0 + w_1*i)
        err=err+obj_err**2
    return err
```

Проверка:

```
In [199]: error_func(w_0=60,w_1=0.05)
Out[199]: 288.99263955579386
```

---

с учетом исправления логической ошибки (подробнее описана в другом ответе):

```
def error_func(w_0=60,w_1=0.05):
    return sum((row['Height'] - (w_0 + w_1*row['Weight']))**2
               for _,row in data.iterrows())
```

проверка:

```
In [208]: error_func(w_0=60,w_1=0.05)
Out[208]: 56.43021375887484
```

---

PS **Но гораздо эффективнее будет воспользоваться [векторизированным решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/842434/211923).**

Answer (score 2):

Судя по вашей формуле вы пытаетесь посчитать суммарное квадратичное отклонение (хотя обычно используют [среднее (`Mean Squared Error`)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error) вместо суммы, чтобы избежать переполнения точности `np.float32/64` при очень больших массивах данных) для линейной регрессии, где `w_0` - `bias` (смещение), а `w_1` - `slope` (угловой коэффициент) в линейной функции:

```
y = w_0 + w_1*x
```

Если `x` задан как вектор (1D) или матрица (2D), то `y` можно посчитать при помощи перемножения матрицы на вектор коэффициентов. Для этого к ветору/матрице `x` *слева*  добавляется столбец, состоящий из единиц. В итоге уравнение преобразуется к виду:

```
y = w_0*1 + w_1*x
```

в матричной форме: (X * W<sup>T</sup>), где `X` - матрица иксов с добавленным слева столбцом из единиц, а `W` - вектор коэффициентов линейного уравнения.

---

Для DataFrame из комментария:

```
In [141]: df
Out[141]:
   Index    Height    Weight
0      1  65.78331  112.9925
1      2  71.51521  136.4873
2      3  69.39874  153.0269
3      4  68.21660  142.3354
4      5  67.78781  144.2971
5      6  68.69784  123.3024
6      7  69.80204  141.4947
7      8  70.01472  136.4623
8      9  67.90265  112.3723
9     10  66.78236  120.6672
```

сначала добавим столбец единиц при помощи [np.column_stack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) и перемножим на вектор коэффициентов линейного уравнения:

```
def hypothesis(X, W):
    return np.dot(np.column_stack((np.ones(len(X)), X)), W)
```

вектор коэффициентов:

```
w = np.array([60, 0.05])
```

расчет `суммарного квадратичного отклонения`:

```
In [189]: ((df['Height'] - hypothesis(df['Height'], w))**2).sum()
Out[189]: 288.99263955579386
```

расчет `Mean Squared Error`:

```
In [190]: ((df['Height'] - hypothesis(df['Height'], w))**2).mean()
Out[190]: 28.899263955579386
```

можно воспользоваться готовой метрикой из модуля `SciKit-Learn`:

```
In [191]: from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

In [192]: mean_squared_error(df['Height'], hypothesis(df['Height'], w))
Out[192]: 28.899263955579386
```

---

У вас похоже присутствует также *логическая ошибка* в функции - вы пытаетесь расчитать/предсказать рост из роста, хотя логично было бы расчитывать рост по весу...

```
In [204]: ((df['Height'] - hypothesis(df['Weight'], w))**2).sum()
Out[204]: 56.43021375887484

In [205]: mean_squared_error(df['Height'], hypothesis(df['Weight'], w))
Out[205]: 5.643021375887484
```